# Django filter if an optional key in json exists

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I have a model `X` with a custom json fied `data` which may or may not have these keys: `key1`, `key2`, `key3`.
I need a way to filter all instances with `key1`.

I have tried doing this:

```
queryset = X.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.annotate(
has_key1=(
    Case(
        When(~Q(data__key1__in=[None, '']), then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=models.BooleanField())
    )
)
```

But `queryset.filter(has_key1=True)` returns nothing yet there are some records with key1.

A direct filter: `queryset.filter(data__key1__in=[1])` works okay.
Anyone with a solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using PosgreSQL with the `JSONField` class? I did not think you can search for keys using that.

Comment: It's a custom jsonfield that serializes python dicts to json dicts and back again. PG is my db

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. There is a `has_key` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.has_key

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL, why not just use `JSONField` or extend it and save yourself from having to rewrite what's already there?

Comment: Cause the `JSONField` does not support serialization of datetimes and other object types

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `has_key` on JSONField.
JSONField and HStoreField share this look up - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#has-key).

```
X.objects.filter(data__has_key='key_1')
```

Here is an example based on my project, I used `has_key` on JSONField in FilterSet (django_filters.rest_framework), to implement filtering by key (if key doesn't exists returns 0 results):

filters.py:

```
class XFilter(FilterSet):
   data_search_by_key =  django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_data_key',
        help_text='Search by key')

   def filter_data_key(self, qs, name, value):
        qs = X.objects.filter(data__has_key=value)
        return qs
```

Answer (score 6):

You can exclude all NULL values and empty strings using:

```
queryset  = queryset.exclude(data__key1__isnull=True).exclude(data__key1__exact='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Django ship with [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) for multiple databases, not just PostgreSQL, which you can import like this:

```
from django.models import JSONField
```

The Django documentation contains instructions on [how to query `JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield). In particular, to answer your question, you can see if a `JSONField` has a particular key by using [`__has_key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#has-key), like this:

```py
>>> Dog.objects.create(name='Meg', data={'owner': 'Bob'})
<Dog: Meg>
>>> Dog.objects.filter(data__has_key='owner')
<QuerySet [<Dog: Meg>]>
```

Comment: FYI our previous room about webapps got frozen, I created another room on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147044/room-for-franck-dernoncourt-and-galacticninja  I wish I didn't have to.